# Explore Alps without a car

Tags: public-transport, italy, transportation, alps

I intend to visit some cities in the Italian Alps (for ex: Belluno, Bolzano) but my greatest wish is in fact to visit the little villages inside the valleys (Siusi, Funes, and so on).

The problem is that I can't drive, and besides that, renting a car would be really expensive for me. I would like to know what are the best ways inside the valleys for transportation. Walking seems to be out of consideration, since the distance between Funes and Bolzano, for example, is about 42 kilometers.

Is there public transportation to the little villages? Is bicycle a good option?

Comment: [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Siusi-Italy/32010-Funes-Province-of-Belluno-Italy) shows bus routes between some of the places you mention, although frequency is limited.

Comment: Maybe electrical bicycle?

Comment: @TomasBy the example in the answer below is 45km of non-stop climbing.  Most e-bike batteries can't do that (the stated range is on the flat).  When the battery runs out, you've got to lug it up the hill.  And if you want to tour you've got the carry the charger in addition to all your kit, and find a way of charging the battery overnight.

Comment: @ChrisH: okay, I have no experience. Carry charger doesn't sound impossible, though? Is it not standard wall socket?

Comment: @Tomas yes, the ones I've seen have been about 2-3x the size and weight of a laptop charger. That probably means an extra piece of luggage on the bike. There are people who do e-bike-touring, but there's a lot of planning involved to be sure they can charge and they're not trying to climb as the battery fades. The interesting little villages tend to be high up and at the end of a day's ride so this could be quite limiting - doable if you're keen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The villages and cities in South Tyrol (Provincia di Bolzano) [are all reachable](http://www.suedtirolmobil.info/sites/default/files/netz_a3.pdf) by public transportation, frequency will vary.

Timetables/Fares are searchable [here](http://www.suedtirolmobil.info/en) (Sorry, poor English translation).
Perhaps a ["holiday ticket"](http://www.suedtirolmobil.info/en/tickets) would be practical.

Answer (score 4):

Bicycle could be a fun way to do it.

(according to komoot) Bolzano to Funes is about 45km with 1000m climb (from start to finish) and would take about 4 hours.

**IF and ONLY IF**

You are an experienced cyclist the mountains (even if the route is not that extreme) and want to carry all your belongings with you; you can't go both way in a single day and enjoy sightseeing (IMO).

**I would not suggest it**.

Other than that, there would different combinations of train and/or buses (according to rome2rio).

Comment: I'd do it. I've ridden in the Alps before.  But incessant climbing for 45 km  (Bolzano to Funes) isn't for everyone, even regular cyclists.  If you're up to the climb, you could do it as a day trip - coming back down will be a lot quicker