# Want to see Alps mountain from nearby areas

Tags: international-travel, alps

I want to have a short term trip around the central Europe to see the Alps mountain from the nearby. I do not want to do camping or hiking or so.Is it possible to go by train to any nearby station to watch these area and which country is the best (I mean maybe the border of Switzerland, Italy, Austria or so)? Some people use train to see all the mountain range while passing I am not sure that is a good idea. I have all the vaccination and resident permit card for eu. Sorry I have no idea how can I do this in a best and cheapest way as a student.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143471/explore-alps-without-a-car Do you mean you want to *tour* the Alps region? Or take a day trip eg https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g188077-Activities-c42-Swiss_Alps.html

Comment: Day trip maybe the best location

Comment: I see you haven't mentioned France, do not underestimate it, some of the highest moutains in the Alps are there.

Comment: Do you want to **see** the mountains, or do you actually want to get **on** the mountains? Also, where are you arriving from, as that would dictate feasibility of a day trip. Finally, when do you want to do this? The "good" periods for this are either in the middle of winter when there's plenty of snow or in the summer when the weather is good, but I'm not quite sure conditions would be ideal right now for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The Alps are very large, so it depends on where and how you want to see them.

IF you want to this "quick and easy" you can go to Germany's tallest mountain which is the Zugspitze right on the Austrian border. You can go all the way up with a cable car. Live cam at https://zugspitze.de/en/News/Live-Info/Zugspitze#

Comment: Thank you. I do not have a car for sure:)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually very easy, if not always really cheap. You can get very close to breathtaking mountains by public transportation in France, Switzerland, Austria, or Italy… Towns that are reachable by train or bus and are in the Alps include Chamonix in France (connection from Saint-Gervais), Zermatt in Switzerland. Grenoble in France or Innsbruck in Austria are larger cities that are also very close to mountains.

If the weather is clear, you will have beautiful views straight from the center of the town and multiple easy walks or cable car journeys to get even closer.

On the more pricey side, Switzerland has world-famous panorama train journeys. All of these countries also have cable cars bringing you to very high mountains with minimal effort (Aiguille du midi, Skyway Mont-Blanc, Wildspitz Bahn, Klein Matterhorn, Zugspitze…) There is also an elevator at the [Jungfrau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_of_Europe) and cogwheel trains in Saint-Gervais, Chamonix or Zermatt (Gornergrat).

Finally, if you go to one of these places, also consider cable cars on the other side of the valley or to lower moutains in the area, they can offer great views of the highest peaks (I am thinking of something like the Brévent in Chamonix but you will need to narrow it down to get specific advice).

Comment: Oh my godness. Thank you. perfect. Which one is the cheapest option for the person in Poland!? So, I need at least  to stay one day in near by area. The train is not that option that I could see the range for example for an hour while passing the route right? Because I heard that some people go by train through the border and see the mountains. do you have any idea about cable cars price average? Where should I catch them? Also, which season is really good? maybe both snow and green?:)  You know price is important for me and I want to go from the first large city you know I am just a passenger

Comment: @AhmadTurani No reason to go to any border specifically, as a Polish resident you can cross them easily and mountains don't start at the border. From Poland Austria is going to be easiest I guess so let's focus on that, even if that's not the highest part of the Alps. Panoramic cable cars can cost €40-60 for a return ticket but it doesn't really make sense to look for the cheapest one if you pay more for the trip. Maybe the Dachstein area could be a good one, Innsbruck is easier to reach but on the other end of the country. You're looking at a 3 day trip at least.

Comment: If you go to the border between Poland and Slovakia, there are nice mountains there (the Tatras) but not the Alps. Is that what you heard about?

Comment: There is also frequent bus service between Geneva (both the airport and the central intercity bus station) and Chamonix.  This is by far faster than the train (roughly 1.5 hours, depending of course on the traffic, instead of 3 or more).

Answer (score 1):

Some mountain ranges are impressive from a distance.
The Alps are from some areas but most of the time they are surrounded by lower mountains and hills.

So your best 'view' of the Alps is from 'inside'.
You can often get train tickets, timed to one train only, which have a good price for international travel.

In Italy, Switzerland and Austria, the main regions of the Alps, you will find youth hostels which, while still not cheap, are less expensive than hotels and often do offer the option to make your own meals, which is also cheaper than going out for dinners in a restaurant.

In your case, no car and a relatively low budget, I would select one city or even village in the Alps and work out a train journey to there and from there to an other town (inside or outside the Alps, as your budget allows you) and by booking early you can see what it will cost you if you buy your tickets on the day you check it.
The earlier you book, the better chance to get cheap tickets. For hostel (and hostel) prices you can look on booking sites, there are several. Search for 'hostel' or 'hotel' and the name of the town or village and most likely a booking site as well as direct links to hostel will  be in the results.

Comment: That's quite a parochial view of the Alps. Italy is just as much in the “main region” of the Alps and there the demarcation between the mountain and the plain tends to be stronger.

Comment: Thanks you. Planning is really hard as I see. Italy seems cheaper but I am not sure I can catch good view trip or not. "I would select one city or even village in the Alps and work out a train journey to there and from there to an other town" this option is also good but which city is important

Comment: I added Italy in the answer, it was just me not going into Italy when in the Alps, which made me forget it writing this answer.